# Angularjs. Radiobutton по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Код шаблона:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 choose-meter" ng-if="serviceHeat">
  <span class="item_titles">{{"DICTIONARY.CHOOSE_METER_VALUE" | translate }}</span>
  <div class="radio custom-radio">
    <label class="radio small col-xs-3" ng-repeat="meterUnit in meterUnits">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="mUnit.id" name="meterUnits" ng-value="meterUnit.id" ng-init="calculateMeters(meter)" ng-readonly="pay.innerState === 'confirm'" required/>
       <span class="radio_styled"></span>
       <span class="radio_text">
          {{"DICTIONARY." + meterUnit.id | translate }}
       </span>
    </label>
    <p>
       {{mUnit.id | json}}
    </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Кусок из контроллера:

```
$scope.meterUnits = [{id:'GC'},{id:'KW'},{id:'MW'},{id:'GJ'}];
$scope.mUnit = [];
```

Необходимо что бы по умолчанию была активна первая кнопка(`GC`). 
Пробовал сделать `$scope.mUnit = [{id:'GC'}];` не помогло. Какие еще варианты?

В итоге получилось

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="mUnit" name="meterUnits" ng-value="meterUnit" ng-click="calculateMeters(meter, mUnit)" ng-readonly="pay.innerState === 'confirm'" required/>
```

Контроллер

```
$scope.meterUnits = ['GC','KW','MW','GJ'];
$scope.mUnit = 'GC';
$scope.calculateMeters = function(meters, meterUnit) {
    if(meterUnit === 'GC'){
        console.log('GC');//TODO: delete
    }
    if(meterUnit === 'KW'){
        console.log('KW');//TODO: delete
    }
    if(meterUnit === 'MW'){
        console.log('MW');//TODO: delete
    }
    if(meterUnit === 'GJ'){
        console.log('GJ');//TODO: delete
    }
}
```

Вопрос. Почему когда стояло ng-change событие срабатывало только при первых нажатиях на кнопки? когда нажимал второй раз(повторно на ту же кнопку), больше не срабатывало. ng-change срабатывает только когда есть изменения? Почему оно не считает каждый следующий клик, изменением?

Comment: Если вы хотите именно первому элементу установить флажок, то можете использовать $index - в директиве ngRepeat это итератор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.mUnit.id` должен содержать значение из `ng-value` т.е. получаем:

`$scope.mUnit = {id:'GC'};`

или для универсальности:

`$scope.mUnit = {id: $scope.meterUnits[0].id};`

**Вариант второй**

Изменяем html:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="mUnit" name="meterUnits" ng-value="meterUnit" ng-init="calculateMeters(meter)" ng-readonly="pay.innerState === 'confirm'" required/>
```

в js

```
$scope.meterUnits = [{id:'GC'},{id:'KW'},{id:'MW'},{id:'GJ'}];
$scope.mUnit = $scope.meterUnits[0];
```

Comment: Да, вчера еще раз попробовал, вариант на подобии $scope.mUnit = {id:'GC'}; то каким то образом сработало(видиом превые попытки что то делал не так) но теперь другая проблема. Данные перестало актульано обновлять. То есть. при клике на кнопку оно передает данные со второга раза. Что бы мне отдать в функцию какой ИД клацнули то дважды нужно нажать на кнопку.